# How do I access a variable passed in an object array from client side to server side in js/googlescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, parameter-passing

New js-er here so appreciate the support. I am passing an object array, `userInfo{}`, which has the following contents **:**

`{"userName":"bob","userID":12345,"userDetail":1}` from a client-side JavaScript using `google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo)`.

Have used `JSON.stringify()` in an alert box to make sure the object array being passed is in the above format and then on the server side I am able to use the data when writing to a googlesheet cell.

```
e.g. ss.getRange(2, userInfo.userID).setValue(userInfo.userName).
```

This works fine.

My issue is when I want to use `userInfo` data in the server side script as a parameter:

`e.g. var newUserDetail = userInfo.userDetail + 5; or if (userInfo.userDetail = 1) {perform action} etc.`

The script does not respond. Do I need to transform the object array elements somehow ? Or use a different syntax to userInfo.userDetail ?

Have searched for on variants of how to access variables passed from client side to server side in js/gs' with no success. I am sure this is super-obvious but still learning - so all help appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `The script does not respond.`?

Comment: Yes, sorry - poor level of detail. For the if statement for example - using: if(userInfo.userDetail = 1)  {perform action} then it will perform action irrespective of whether userDetail is 1 or not…

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `For the if statement for example - using: if(userInfo.userDetail = 1) {perform action} then it will perform action irrespective of whether userDetail is 1 or no`, if you doesn't miscopy your script, I think that `if(userInfo.userDetail = 1)` is required to be `if(userInfo.userDetail == 1)`. How about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be the way you are writing the condition inside of your if statement. In javascript, to compare two values you should use either `==` or `===`.

`==` is used to compare two values regardless of their types, for example `console.log("22" == 22)` will print true. While `console.log("22" === 22)` will print false.

You mention your if statement having the condition `userInfo.userDetail = 1`, while it should be `userInfo.userDetail === 1`

Comment: Exactly this - thanks Deor, appreciate!

Comment: If this helped answer your question please mark my post as the answer :D